# Comments only posting to most recent status update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The news feed on the sites dashboard I'm working on has multiple items from different users; and can also be commented on. However, whenever you write a comment under each post, it only posts to the post at the top of the feed (the most recent one). Comments are posted instantly by pressing the enter key, which then runs this JS code which is on the index.php page.

```
$(function(){
$('#comment_body').live( 'keypress' , function (e) {
    var boxVal = $(this).val();
    var sendTo = $('#to_id').val();
    if ( e.keyCode == '13' ) {
e.preventDefault();
        $.post( 'instantcom.php' , { 'comment_body' :  boxVal , 'activity_id' : sendTo } , function () {
            // reload data or just leave blank
        } );
        $('#comment_body').val('');
    }
} );
});
```

Then, the HTML for the comment box on each post is as follows:

```
<p align="center" style="height:45px;">
<input type="text" name="comment_body" id="comment_body" style="margin-top:12px;border:1px solid blue !important;width:329px;height:21px;"  />
<span class=" glyphicons-icon camera" style="position:relative;bottom:50px;left:155px;"></span></p>
<input name="type" type="hidden" value="a" />
<input name="activity_id" id="to_id" type="hidden" value="' . $act_item_id . '" />
```

The ' . $act_item_id . ' is just a PHP variable which contains the unique ID of the status update.

So then, any ideas as to why comments are only posting to the most recent posts instead of the ones they're meant to post to?

Comment: Are you duplicating the id `to_id` for every post? That's a DOM no-no. They must be unique.

Comment: @DevlshOne the $act_item_id holds the unique ID in to_id in this line of code: <input name="activity_id" id="to_id" type="hidden" value="' . $act_item_id . '" />

Answer (score 0):

You're using an id to identify which post you're commenting against? to_id right? Well, that's an id on the page, id's should be unique to the page.

Comment: do you mean this? <input name="activity_id" id="to_id" type="hidden" value="' . $act_item_id . '" />

Comment: Yep. That's the line. You cannot repeat `id="to_id"` throughout the DOM. It's a blatant violation of the W3C standards.